# Replacing 0x1021 polynomial with 0x8005 in this CRC-16 code

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic, error-correcting-codes, mathematical-analysis, crc

I found a highly optimized [CRC-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) implementation originally intended for microcontrollers. It is noticeably faster than the traditional method, but is hard-coded to model the specific unreflected polynomial `0x1021`, or x^12 + x^5 + x^0.

I was then able to determine, when slightly modified, the reflected variant of this polynomial can be modelled as well, which is `0x8408`, or x^15 + x^10 + x^3. This is achieved by changing bit shift direction as well as the polynomial shifts. Though I'm unsure of the specifics of how it works. I've also found examples of CRC-32 that use this approach, but require many more operations.

Now, I am wondering if it is possible to use this same approach to use other polynomials, specifically `0x8005`, or x^15 + x^2 +x^0. To do so I need to understand what this code is doing, but it's highly cryptic. This is a essentially an edge case of CRC, amounting to clever usage of bitwise optimizations.

Here is the code for the unreflected CRC-16 using polynomial `0x1021`:

```js
// in JavaScript, but easily translates to C etc.
function crc16(data, crc = 0, xorout = 0) {
    for(let i = 0, t; i < data.length; i++, crc &= 0xFFFF) {
        t = (crc >> 8) ^ data[i]; // shift high crc byte over
        t = (t ^ t >> 4);
        crc <<= 8; // shift left 1 byte
        crc ^= (t << 12) ^ (t << 5) ^ (t);
    }
    return crc ^ xorout;
}
```

This can model CRC-16 variants such as XMODEM or "CCITT-FALSE" depending on the initial value of `crc` and `xorout`.

The `crc` variable stores the current CRC value, while the `t` variable is temporary storage for intermediate calculations. The expression `(t << 12) ^ (t << 5) ^ (t)` appears to model the actual polynomial, which gets XOR'd into the CRC for every byte of input.

For `0x8005`, also an unreflected polynomial, one might assume a drop in replacement such as `(t << 15) ^ (t << 2) ^ (t)` would do the trick, but it does not work. In fact, in that code, the `(t << 12)` cannot be changed, though other terms can, if they're less than `(t << 8)`. So this only covers polynomials 4096 through 4607.

As I said before, I was able to correctly model the reflected version of `0x1021` as well using a similar construction. Here is the code for that:

```js
function crc16b(data, crc = 0, xorout = 0) {
    for(let i = 0, t; i < data.length; i++, crc &= 0xFFFF) {
        t = (crc) ^ data[i];
        t = (t ^ t << 4) & 255; // &255 is to remove overflow
        crc >>= 8; // shift right 1 byte
        crc ^= (t << 8) ^ (t >> 4) ^ (t << 3);
    }
    return crc ^ xorout;
}
```

This code correctly models the reflected variants such as CCITT-TRUE, ISO/IEC 14443 among others.

The code is slightly different to account for it being reflected, but the structure is essentially the same.  However the expression that represents the polynomial is a bit strange: `(t << 8) ^ (t >> 4) ^ (t << 3)`. It doesn't seem to line up with the expected polynomial representation x^15 + x^10 + x^3.

The polynomial I want to translate to this structure is `0x8005` (or its reflected version, `0xA001`). It has both reflected and unreflected variants. I am referencing the different CRC-16 variants and vectors from here: http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm

This page uses a test string "123456789", to check implementation correctness, so I typically check it as an array:

```js
crc16([49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57])
```

And these are the expected values for two CRC-16 variants I am targeting (which use `0x8005` polynomial or `0xA001` reversed):

```
For init=0x0000 and xorout=0x0000
----------------------------------
CRC-16/UMTS (unreflected) = 0xfee8
CRC-16/ARC  (reflected)   = 0xbb3d
```

What I want to do is modify the above code to implement the polynomials `0x8005` and `0xA001`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how it even works in the first place.  I figured `0x8005` would be a good fit because of the few number of bits which are used.

Any ideas on how this is actually implementing CRC-16, or what might be required to translate other polynomials?

A classic resource on CRC is [A Painless Guide to CRC Error Detection Algorithms](https://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt)

---

Also if it helps, here are traditional implementations of CRC-16 (but are less efficient):

These implementations allow any polynomial to be supplied as input. Here is the unreflected version:

```js
// Targets XMODEM
var crc16 = function(data) {
    var POLY = 0x1021, INIT = 0, XOROUT = 0;
    for(var crc = INIT, i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        crc = crc ^ (data[i] << 8);
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            crc = crc & 0x8000 ? crc << 1 ^ POLY : crc << 1;
        }
    }
    return (crc ^ XOROUT) & 0xFFFF;
};
```

And the reflected equivalent (notice the change of shift direction...):

```js
// Targets KERMIT
var crc16b = function(data) {
    var POLY = 0x8408, INIT = 0, XOROUT = 0;
    for(var crc = INIT, i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        crc = crc ^ data[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            crc = crc & 1 ? crc >> 1 ^ POLY : crc >> 1;
        }
    }
    return (crc ^ XOROUT) & 0xFFFF;
};
```

Comment: Is your question about a problem in your code? That makes it more on-topic for [so]. Either way, it would seem helpful to go in armed with a working definition of CRC in your question, and an explanation of what the `^=` is doing in the first place. If you don’t know that, ask that question first. (I’m not saying you don’t know; I’m trying to avoid assuming too much. I had a hard time following the question, so I’m really saying it could use some clarity, as it sounds like part of the problem is the code...)

Comment: Code works fine. This is a highly specific method of implementing CRC-16 with a specific polynomial, optimized for speed, using bitwise tricks. CRC is a type of checksum or "cyclic redundancy code". I am trying to understand the logic behind this algorithm (not CRC in general), and adapt it for a different polynomial. I'll try to clarify and add comments. I posted at CS thinking there'd be people more versed in studying algorithms here.

Comment: `[is it] possible to use this same approach [using] other polynomials` I take the approach to be *partial evaluation*, which is valid generally. There are different approaches to implementing the core operation, from [using a lookup table](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/61data/CRC16.java) over implementing it in a general purpose processor (fixed polynomial, e.g. CRC32 using 0x11EDC6F41, or implementing "carryless multiplication") to having a ["compiler"](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_crc.pdf) configure "field programmable" hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but there is no magic formula. Each polynomial requires a unique set of operations, and the number of operations required can vary highly. A solid grasp of CRC math is also necessary to craft these solutions. Unfortunately I only have a cursory understanding, so my explanation may be limited.

The best way to illustrate this is to compare them. Here's the code for `0x1021`:

```c
 t = (c >> 8) ^ d;
 t ^= t >> 4;
 c = (c << 8) ^ (t << 12) ^ (t << 5) ^ t;
```

And here is the equivalent for `0x8005`:

```c
 t = (c >> 8) ^ d;
 z = t;
 t ^= t >> 4;
 t ^= t >> 2;
 t ^= t >> 1;
 t &= 1;
 t |= z << 1;
 c = (c << 8) ^ (t << 15) ^ (t << 1) ^ t;
```

As you can see, the code required to implement different polynomials, can be highly variable. The second implementation requires more operations and intermediates.

The `0x1021` polynomial appears to require very few operations, and so it's a good choice for microcontrollers which are slower and have little RAM. It may be unique in this regard.